# React Native Expo app how to unregister from Notifications

Tags: react-native, notifications, expo

In my react native expo app I am successfully registering to the notification service with `Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync()` and it is working without issue, my question is, how do I stop receiving notifications? Is there a way to clear the push token on the device only?

The problem I am having is if a user logs out and a different user logs in on the same device, they will still receive the previous users notifications since the device still is still registered. `Notifications.removePushTokenSubscription()` seemed like it may work but it only removes the push token listener created with `Notifications.addPushTokenListener()` which (I think) is unrelated to this issue

My current logout function attempt looks like this:

```
  const logOutUser = async(notificationToken) => {
    if(notificationToken){
      var subscription = await Notifications.addPushTokenListener(notificationToken);
      await Notifications.removePushTokenSubscription(subscription);
    }
  }
```

Am I thinking about this problem wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can't unregistered from Notifications, there is no function that does that simply because the expo token is related to your device,not your account, instead you can do this:

> 1. When user login you should send the **expo token** to your back end
>    and store it in an **array of expoTokens**, because user can have his
>    account open in multiple phones.

> 2. Store the expo token in your
>    **AsyncStorage**.

> 3. When the user **logout** you should **delete the expo token** from array of expoTokens  array in your Backend Database.

> 4. and finely **delete** it from AsyncStorage .

Hope it works for you!

Comment: Unfortunately, this will not suffice when the user do an offline logout..  even using a queue + background services to de-register a token when the user gets online will not prevent notifications already sent from reaching the user

Comment: do i need to store expo token in AsyncStorage?

Comment: you need to store somehow because we need it to send the notifications